# How to read csv file in pandas if the pathname contains single inverted comma and i get error?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

My Code :

```
df1=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\YUNUS'S LAPTOP\Desktop\Book1.csv')
df1
```

Error I get :

```
  Input In [20]
    df1=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\YUNUS'S LAPTOP\Desktop\Book1.csv')
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Try it with double quotes in the path string. df1=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\YUNUS'S LAPTOP\Desktop\Book1.csv"). Not sure if it would work but worth try.

Comment: Use the escape operator (  \  ) so that python will consider that inverted comma part of the string instead of end of the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `"` rather than `'` for the bonds of the string, like so

`df1 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\YUNUS'S LAPTOP\Desktop\Book1.csv")`